# how to fix error when using the React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, navigation-drawer, react-native-reanimated

Im getting this error

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts: C:\Work\WordHunt\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts: Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`.
  5 | export * from './reanimated1';
  6 | export * from './reanimated2';
> 7 | export * as default from './Animated';
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  8 |
```

What Im getting on the phone:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suoug.jpg

when I try to use createDrawerNavigator:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Main from './Screens/Main';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

This is my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './src/Components/Screens/Main';
import MyDrawer from './src/Components/SideMenu';

function App() {
  return (
    <MyDrawer />
  )
}

export default App;
```

IM using react native cli, not expo

Comment: Im on Windows machine

Comment: "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0", solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This helps me:                                                             https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/846#issuecomment-944115333

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

```
//firstly you need to configure your babel.config.js

module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
//add this plugins
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First run this to make sure everything compatible:

```
expo update 


npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

npx pod-install ios
```

Comment: It doesn't help, and Im not use expo

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started 
Read Through this dec and you will find what exactly you should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Main from './Screens/Main';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MyDrawer() {
  return (
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator  useLegacyImplementation={true} initialRouteName="Main">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```